# MOTO Acronym for MTG Online

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-online

Some people refer to Magic: The Gathering Online as "MOTO" or "MODO". None of them can tell me what it stands for, so at first, I thought they just got the acronym wrong. It turns out to be pretty popular, that's all I've been able to find out. The term is not in the [Magic Jargon article](http://www.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtgcom/academy/9), and not one person in [this](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-general/319263-i-hate-the-magic-snobs-elitist-at-the-local-shop) thread spelled it out.

What does MOTO stand for? Is it different from MODO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic%3a_The_Gathering_Online) claims that this is **an acronym from earlier in its development which was later discontinued**:

> WotC was sufficiently convinced and contracted LLS to develop the
>   service, which was then known as Magic Online with Digital Objects
>   (MODO). Initially, the idea of charging for virtual goods, as opposed
>   to a subscription model with unlimited access, was greeted with
>   skepticism. Additionally, concerns were floated over how solid the
>   server and trading code would be;[6] if exploits were found, the
>   entire economy could easily be destroyed. After a period of
>   beta-testing, the game became available to the general public in June
>   2002. The name was changed from MODO to its final commercial title, Magic: The Gathering Online (MTGO).

The game apparently gained [some notoriety during its development](http://www.starcitygames.com/magic/misc/6985_The_MODO_FiascoCorporate_Hubris_and_Magic_Online.html) under this name, which may have caused it to stick.  It's likely that this is simply an affectionate hold-over nickname from a time when this old name was relevant.

Comment: It's also easy to say, rather than spell. "Moh-doe," versus "Em-tee-gee-oh."

Comment: @Brian I believe the proper way to say it is "Mo' Dough" as in "It's another way for Wizards to extract mo' dough from our wallets"

Comment: In addition to all of this, it's worth noting that the acronym was used to name the original executable; the actual program that was run on players' systems was modo.exe .  That's where most folks' exposure to the name came from.